# Facebook app nagging about syncing. Can it be disabled?

Tags: applications, facebook

While only a minor issue, it is annoying. I've had a look at the settings for the facebook app, but even after disabling anything that did seem relevant to this message popping up, it still keeps showing. The app was not pre-installed on the phone, it was added by my own will, if that is any relevant information.

Is there any way to disable this, or is it a cruel "feature" added to the facebook app that can not be disabled?

[image: This is what it looks like.]

Comment: Are you sure this is coming from the Facebook app? You can check by long-tapping the notification to bring up a menu, then **App info** on that menu.

Comment: Ouh... Hard to say, I tend to simply dismiss the message, and it's kinda random when it pops up, so, can't try that right now. Tho, I am quite sure it started when I did install the Facebook app. I'll see if it pops up again during the day, and I'll check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By request from 'Dan Hulme' who replied to my question, I got the message to pop up again and managed to get the app-info. It turns out to be an app connected to the Facebook app called 'SNS'. I simply removed the tick from the "Show notifications" option. The message no longer pops up.

It can otherwise be found on "Settings -> More -> Application manager" Shuffle so you see the "All" list, then scroll down til you find the SNS application.

Comment: In case you're wondering what that SNS is, it stands for Social Network Service. Usually it's the preinstalled syncs or widgets that use this.